# Swift equivalent objective code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm new to xcode. I would like to convert below objective c code to swift equivalent.

```
ActionStringCancelBlock cancel = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
    NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the swift equivalent:

```
let cancel: ActionStringCancelBlock = { (picker: ActionSheetStringPicker) in
    NSLog("Block Picker Canceled")
}
```

Suggested reading: [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_152)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just do:

```
let cancel: ActionStringCancelBlock = { (picker: ActionSheetStringPicker!) in
    println("Block Picker Canceled")
    return
}
```

but you might get away with:

```
let cancel: ActionStringCancelBlock = {
    println("Block Picker Canceled")
}
```